Populating MOLEX receptacles at industrial scale
I am a manufacturing engineer charged with implementing process improvements that reduce the total time to build an article. Our volume is such that a one minute reduction in labour results in £1K-£2K annual savings. It may not sound like much, but since my goal is to remove up to 17 minutes from the process this year, the savings will add up.
One process our operators perform is populating a MOLEX receptacle with 5 pre-terminated wires (this one to be exact). Presently, operators are starting the terminals in the receptacle by hand, then finishing installation with what I can only describe as an awl. MOLEX has already recommended that I implement a proper tool to finish installation, which I am considering.
Watching the operators do the work manually seems very tedious: approximately 40 seconds per article. Online research has not been fruitful: the content I have found is aimed at hobbyists. So what I'm wondering is if there are other tools or processes in the market that are designed to build MOLEX assemblies at an industrial scale?

Take a look at something like this https://youtu.be/9um0EqVdNuA?si=ucwxplWxhiXk17nY. Fully automated assembly is possible, but it sounds like you're in that horrible middle ground volume where you're at enough volume for labour costs to be high, but not high enough to justify large capital outlay on machinery like this.

Hello and welcome.  One of my clients had very similar issues, and eventually outsourced the cabling subassemblies to a company which specialised in this work; quality was higher and unit costs much lower; there were some additional managerial costs to do with agreeing specifications; also additional friction for international trading; lead times became a lot more important when it was out of house.  Have you considered this?  Alternatively, is there anything ready-made you can use/adapt: Mouser and Farnell appear to sell them ready-terminated, others must as well.

@mountainred you are spot on. Based on previous business proposals I've written, it's really challenging to implement anything over £10K when the time savings is on the order of tens of seconds. That video is a cool watch nonetheless.

@jonathanjo due to some process constraints - through hole clearance namely - we cannot receive the MOLEX pre-populated. We have to pass the terminations through a small hole, then build the assembly. The other end of the cables terminates in an assembly that we receive from a supplier of OTS parts. This was a DfM oversight, unfortunately.

My other suggestion would be to make really good jigs: that hold the parts in exactly the right place, with "funnels" to easily point each wire into where it's supposed to go.  Laser-cut acrylic is a great way to make such things which can be very accurate indeed.  (3d printing and prototype mills also good).  Holding anything still or aiming anything with hand-eye coordination is probably where most of your 40 seconds are going.  (This is in fact what the one of our outsourced companies did: make really good jigs so the workers can go very quickly.)
